# Multiple files upload using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, multiple-file-upload

I'm working on a webapp and I'm using multiple files upload, but it doesn't work with AJAX. 
For multiple files upload i use the Apache FileUpload which is working perfectly but after using Ajax the ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent() returns False.

Thanks for your help

Here is my JSP code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Envoi des fichiers RNP</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fileupload.js"></script>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Envoi de fichier</legend>
                <label for="fichier">Emplacement du premier fichier <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="file" id="fichier" name="fichiers[]" multiple value="<c:out value="${fichier.nom}"/>"/>
                <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['fichier']}</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" id="showTable"/>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="tablediv">
            <table cellspacing="0" id="site2G">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">CGI</th>
                    <th scope="col">BSC</th>
                    <th scope="col">Site Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cells</th>
                    <th scope="col">EA</th>         
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

and my AJAX code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {$("#tablediv").hide();
 $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

     $.ajax({
            url: "Upload",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(responseJson) {
                if(responseJson!=null){
                    $("#site2G").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    var table1 = $("#site2G");
                    $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
                         var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                            rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['bsc']);
                            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['sitename']);
                            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['cells']);
                            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['cgi']);
                            rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['ea']);
                            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                    });
                    }
                }
          });
        $("#tablediv").show();}); });
```

Comment: You need to check in the network tab those files are getting uploaded there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer third party plugins to upload your multiple files to server

A few that i will recommend are

- [Jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)
- [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

They support

> multiple file upload.
>
> progress bar
>
> what to do after file has successfully uploaded
>
> Image preview

Comment: _For security reason you cannot use jquery ajax_ how come? Where did you find it? Don't you know its possible with `FormData()+jQuery.ajax()`?

Comment: @Jai No i didnt know that and i googled it yes it is possible.. and i have edited my answer ... sorry for wrong information

Comment: and only with **html5**.

Comment: Thanks @Jai so what you recommend, using a plugin or my own custom jquery code  for file upload next time

Comment: That depends on UI if i have to do i mostly write my own but for quick solution is to use some other plugins which provides some additional benefits/features also.

Comment: @Jai Thank you for your answer. I choosed to work with a JQuery plugin and it worked perfectly. thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I used the following function for upload

```
$.upload = function(url, form, _callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "POST", 
        processData:false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: form,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, request){
            if(typeof _callback == "function")
                _callback.call(this, data);
        },
        error:function(data, textStatus, request){
            if(typeof _callback == "function")
                _callback.call(this, data);
        }
    });
};
```

To call this function

```
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i=0;i<$("#upload #file").get(0).files.length;i++)
   formData.append("file" + i, $("#upload #file").get(0).files[i]);


$.upload("Upload", formData, function(data){
    //success or failure check
});
```

Your HTML is

```
<form id="upload" style="display:none">
    <input name="file" id="file" type="file" multiple />
</form>
```

Comment: issue is different. there is `multiple` attribute in the file.

Comment: it is also possible by looping through files[i] and naming the append with unique field names like file1, file2, file3

Answer (score 0):

like Dickens proposed , but the code is little differently formatted:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    var $uploader = $("#FileUpload_doc")[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < $uploader.files.length; i++)
        formData.append("file_" + i, $uploader.files[i]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your url here',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function (dataReceived) {
     // do another things here
    }).fail(function (a, b, c) {
        alert(a, b, c);
    });
```