# select single, mulitple files in a input field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**The Question**

Lets say I have a form with an input: `<input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file[]" multiple>`.

If the user selects the files separately instead of CTRL+Click to select multiple files at once, then I will always only get 1 as a result if I call `document.getElementById("upload_file").files.length;` and the file will always be the last one I selected.

Is there a way to let the user select x files separately and still be able to upload x files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `then I will always only get 1 as a result`...yes, because that only selects one file. If they then make another selection, it removes the previous selection and replaces it with the new one. That's how the input box works. You're not doing anything wrong.

Comment: `Is there a way`...either provide separate inputs on-screen, or build something which triggers an AJAX upload on every "change" event of the input, regardless how many times the user changes it. There are a few AJAX-file-upload GUIs around which people have built, which you might use for inspiration or simply decide to adopt. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584007/5947043, but that's a few years old, you can probably find more with some simple searches online.